# Booting into ClockworkMod

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have a Samsung S2 which has been rooted for some time with many application using root Rom Manager shows CWM 2 installed however it always boots to 3e. I would like to update to lollipop but with the multikey shortcut always going to 3e I want. How can I change the rom to boot to CWM2

Comment: Which ROM are you using? Have you tried the command `adb reboot-recovery`? You would need [tag:adb] installed in PC.

Comment: No matter what method I used to enter recovery it always bring up the original recovery program 3e

Answer (score 0):

You can simply boot into recovery using  [Reboot Recovery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.qbanin.reboot) app.